# Lxml check if element is there and get href of sibling if true

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, lxml, html-select

I want to check if a specific element has text and if true I want to get the href of a sibling element. There are multiple Products like this on the site and I want to check each one for availability.
Html looks roughly like this:

```
<div class="card-body">
   <div class="badge">
      <div>
         <span class="badge-text"> Sold</span>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="image">
      </a href="test.com">
   </div>
</div>
```

First I want to check if "sold" is there and if true I want to get the href. There are multiple of these products so i have to check each one of them.
Hope you can help

Comment: Can you use `beautifulsoup`?

Comment: Please always provide a minimum reproducible work/code snippets in order to reproduce the error/problem and thus provide you some way around to solve it. 

https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: No I cannot use beautifulsoup because I'm working with variables and soup.find_all() is not working with variables. Also I didnt even know how to start so couldn't provide any code snippets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably looking for something like

```
doc.xpath('//div[@class="card-body"][.//span[@class="badge-text"][contains(text(),"Sold")]]//div[@class="image"]//@href')[0]
```

Output should be

```
'test.com
```